# Pandas - How can I change the values of a column based on a given non-python dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (i've filtered it down to the important parts):

```
              INC_KEY               PTOCCUPATIONALINDUSTRY
96       170000016620                       Other Services
127      170000016651                       Other Services
170      170000016694                        Manufacturing
181      170000016706                         Construction
268      170000016793                       Other Services
```

I was also given a 'dictionary' (not a python dictionary), that looks like this:

[image: Dictionary]

My task is to convert the values in PTOCCUPATIONALINDUSTRY to the numbers that you see in the dictionary. Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I need to manually do if statements for each value?

The reason I'm looking for a shortcut is because I need to do this exact task over ~30 different columns, so it would take forever to do it manually.

Comment: Im still not clear what is the expected output

Comment: in what form is the dictionary presented? Is this a txt file?

Comment: Presumably you'd need to turn that text file/document/structure into a python dictionary. Then the standard pandas `map` replace` operations would work as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your dict :

```
map_dict = {"Finance, Insurance, and Real Estate": 1, "etc...}
```

Then, simply do :

```
df["PTOCCUPATIONALINDUSTRY"] = df["PTOCCUPATIONALINDUSTRY"].map(map_dict)
```